# Yii2: Writing to database the date/time of the current record via expression

Tags: php, database, yii2

There is table with some columns. One of it `date_of_record`. Means the date when current row is inserted in database. In current version i just calculate this field in `PHP` code before save().

How it should be correctly done via expression? Example by opportunity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Timestamp Behaviors** In Controller :

```
use yii\db\Expression;

public function behaviors()
{
  return [
    [
        'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
        'createdAtAttribute' => 'date_of_record',
        'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
    ],
  ];
}
```

**References**

1) [Timestamp Behaviors](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-timestampbehavior.html)
2) [Concept Behaviors](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-behaviors.html)

Comment: @user199588 Yes , you can but it's mysql function and make sure you have correct data type in db to store date. Use [CURDATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)

Comment: What about defining the table row `default value` `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` ?